# .load does not work in jQuery on button click

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to load a PHP file when a person click on a button, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="card-body" style="background-color:#1f1f1f;">

</div>

<button id="power-on-phone" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#power-on-phone").click(function(){
            $(".card-body").load("phoneHome.php");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If someone clicks on the "power-on-phone" button, it supposes to load the PHP file inside the .card-body but it never does.

When I go to developer mode by clicking F12, I saw an error that shows:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is the version of jQuery I'm using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Which is located in the  tag

Comment: How are you embeding jQuery script? and which version are you using?

Comment: This is what I'm using: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: This is the thing I'm using:<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> which is located in the <head> tag

Comment: And the script you are showing here is it after or before the jQuery call? This fiddle uses the same version : https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/2z5dymL9/

Comment: @Ultra Can you edit your question to add those details?

Comment: Okay, I will edit it

Comment: @Bilel the script is before the jQuery call.

Comment: No it should be after :) jquery wasn't loaded yet... Put it after Jquery and it should work

Comment: You mean like add the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> after the script that has all the functions?

Comment: No the opposite :)

Comment: Okay, I did that but it never works